# Frida not hooking function in private process

Tags: android, frida

Frida client v12.11.11 on Ubuntu 18.06

Frida Server v12.11.17 on Android Studio emulator (Android 9.0 Google X86_ARM)

I am trying to hook the onCreate method of a subclass that implements a service running in a private process. This is the manifest declaration:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="my_subclass_to_hook" android:process=":my_process">
```

In order to perform the hook I followed the example reported here:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/97331588304/

I'am able to detect when the process is being called since the spawn_added event is correctly working inside the jscode code. But the hooking implementation function is not being called.

I am sure that the original function is being called since I can see the logcat prints.

Can anyone help me please? I've got stuck for weeks on this issue.
Am I missing anything or is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Following is the Python code I am using. As I said I am able to catch when the service process "my_app_package:my_process" is created since the jscode is correctly called and I can see the "Script called..." print. Problem is that the hooked function my_subclass_to_hook.onCreate is not being attached since I cannot see the "Hooked!!" print. By the way I am sure that the function my_subclass_to_hook.onCreate is being called since I can see the prints in the logcat. Hoping this can clarify my problem:

```
import codecs
import frida
import time
import sys
import threading

device = frida.get_device_manager().enumerate_devices()[-1]
print(device)

pending = []
sessions = []
scripts = []
event = threading.Event()

jscode = """

console.log("Script called...");

Java.perform(function x() { 

    var my_class = Java.use("my_subclass_to_hook");

    my_class.onCreate.implementation = function (a) {        
        console.log("Hooked!!");
        var ret_value = this.onCreate(a);
        return ret_value;
    }
"""

def on_spawned(spawn):
    print('on_spawned:', spawn)
    pending.append(spawn)
    event.set()

def spawn_added(spawn):
    print('spawn_added:', spawn)
    event.set()
    if(spawn.identifier.startswith('my_app_package:my_process')):        
        session = device.attach(spawn.pid) 
        script = session.create_script(jscode)
        script.on('message', on_message)
        script.load()
        device.resume(spawn.pid)
        print('Resumed')

def spawn_removed(spawn):
    print('spawn_removed:', spawn)
    event.set()

def on_message(spawn, message, data):
    print('on_message:', spawn, message, data)

def on_message(message, data):
    if message['type'] == 'send':
        print("[*] {0}".format(message['payload']))
    else:
        print(message)

def child_added(spawn):
    print('child_added:', spawn)

device.on('spawn-added', spawn_added)
device.on('spawn-removed', spawn_removed)
device.on('child-added', child_added)
device.on('child-removed', on_spawned)
device.on('process-crashed', on_spawned)
device.on('output', on_spawned)
device.on('uninjected', on_spawned)
device.on('lost', on_spawned)
device.enable_spawn_gating()
event = threading.Event()
print('Enabled spawn gating')

pid = device.spawn(["my_app_package"])

session = device.attach(pid)
device.resume(pid)
sys.stdin.read()
```

Comment: Are you sure that frida is also active in the service process? Because I am not sure if the app process will spawn/fork the service process. May be the process is directly created by Android. Second you should post the relevant parts of the used frida hooking code. Otherwise it is difficult to tell if it may work or not and why.

Comment: Hi Robert thanks for your reply. I have updated my question putting the php code. Hoping this can help to clarify my problem.

Comment: It is Python code, not php. Hooking the onCreate method of the service can be a bit problematic as it is executed very early and if frida attaches later you will never see this call again. Hence for testing I would hook a method that is called regularly or that can be triggered from outside (e.g. from the app).

Comment: That's strange since "spawn_added" detects when the 'my_app_package:my_process' is spwaned, shouldn't the onCreate be called after the spawn catching? Problem is that this subprocess is being created as soon as the app starts so no way to trigger from outside (is there any way to do this?). By the way this problem happens only when I want to hook function in the service process. If I try to catch the onCreate of the main app process (with the same script) the hook works perfectly. Do you know if there is a better way to perform the hooking of method in the app subprocesses? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the overload.

```
my_class.onCreate.implementation = function (a) {

}
```

should be

```
my_class.onCreate.overload('android.os.Bundle').implementation = function (bundle)
{
 .....
}
```

That's a very jank way of calling a frida script. You should have a sleep(1) between the script.load() and script.resume()